'AsyncStream' object is not iterable when streaming openAI Assistant thread runs
I am currently trying to stream a response with openAIs new assistant update. I followed the official documentation here but it doesn't want to work. I keep getting this error:
File "/home/vscode/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/openai/lib/streaming/_assistants.py", line 404, in __stream__
    for event in stream:
TypeError: 'AsyncStream' object is not iterable

Here is my api endpoint:
@router.post("/new")
async def post_new(request: Request):
    """Start a new chat."""
    ...
        thread = await client.beta.threads.create()
        await client.beta.threads.messages.create(
            thread_id=thread.id,
            content=content_start,
            role="user",
            metadata={"type": "hidden"},
        )
        # create the streamed thread run here
        async with client.beta.threads.runs.stream(
            thread_id=thread.id,
            assistant_id=request.state.assistant_id,
            event_handler=EventHandler(),
        ) as stream:
            print("\n\nStream started")  # this is printed

            
            stream.until_done() # calling this fails

The only difference is that I add async to with client.beta.threads.runs.stream() otherwise I run into this error:
/workspace/backend/routers/chat.py:54: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'AsyncAPIClient.post' was never awaited
  with client.beta.threads.runs.stream(

I use python 3.12 here with openAI version 1.25.1 (I've also tried older versions of both) and fastAPI for my backend.

Edit Solution:
Ok so the solution of this error, in case someone stumbles over the same issue, is that the EventHandler needs to be Asynchronous too unlike shown in the example.

from openai import AsyncAssistantEventHandler
from typing_extensions import override


class EventHandler(AsyncAssistantEventHandler):
    def __init__(self, response_stream) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.response_stream = response_stream

    @override
    async def on_text_delta(self, delta, snapshot):
        print("\n on_text_delta", delta.value, end="", flush=True)
        return delta.value
...


I see the constructor takes a parameter, but you're calling it with an empty constructor. In my case it wants the response_stream object - what are you sending?
